# Eclipse Java Debugging Error "Source not found." when adding items to Android spinner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-spinner, android-adapter

Hey I am trying to add items to a spinner using eclipse for android and when the following line is executed:

```
fromList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the debugger says

> Source not found.

here's my java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");
    list.add("Item 4");
    list.add("Item 5");

    fromList = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrom);
    CharSequence[] itemArray = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.temperature_units);
    List<CharSequence> itemList = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(
            Arrays.asList(itemArray));
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemList);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            fromList.setAdapter(adapter);       // THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) is a class from the Android SDK.

You will need to download the Android SDK source code, and attach it to the project spurces, so you can debug this class (and other Android SDK classes)

--- UPDATE 1 ---

Please have a look at [this blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/android/attach-android-source-code-to-eclipse-ide/) to attach your andriod sources and debug them.

Comment: okay i have it downloaded but how do i attach it to the project sources?

Comment: Updated my answer with a link, with the steps needed for acomplishing the source attachment

Answer (score 0):

Get Android SDK source code as @Cristian Meneses told and import it into your main activity:

import android.widget.Spinner; (Ctrl+Shift+O).